# joining two dataframes having duplicate row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following two dataframes

df1

```
+--------+-----------------------------
|id  | amount       | fee             | 
|1   | 10.00        | 5.0             |
|3   | 90           | 130.0           |
```

df2

```
+--------+--------------------------------
|exId  | exAmount     | exFee            | 
|1     | 10.00        | 5.0              |
|1     | 10.0         | 5.0              |
|3     | 90.0         | 130.0              |
```

I am joining between them using all three columns and trying to identify columns which are common between the two dataframes and the ones which are not.

I'm looking for output:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------
|id  | amount       | fee  |exId  | exAmount | exFee | 
|1   | 10.00        | 5.0  |1     | 10.0     | 5.0   |
|null| null         | null |1     | 10.0     | 5.0   |
|3   | 90           | 130.0|3     | 90.0     | 130.0 |
```

Basically want the duplicate row in df2 with exId 1 to be listed separately.
Any thoughts?

Comment: output shouldn't change. basically one occurance of row should match with one occurance of same row in second dataframe. If either of them have extra row(duplicate), it should not match.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan don't have to worry about 10.0 vs 10.00. Can keep it as integer if that makes thing clean.

Comment: No they shouldn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One of the possible way* is to *group by all three columns and generate row numbers for each dataframe* and *use that additional column in addition to the rest three columns while joining*. You should get what you desire.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("id", "amount", "fee").orderBy("fee")
def windowSpec2 = Window.partitionBy("exId", "exAmount", "exFee").orderBy("exFee")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df1.withColumn("sno", row_number().over(windowSpec1)).join(
  df2.withColumn("exSno", row_number().over(windowSpec2)),
  col("id") === col("exId") && col("amount") === col("exAmount") && col("fee") === col("exFee") && col("sno") === col("exSno"), "outer")
  .drop("sno", "exSno")
  .show(false)
```

and you should be getting

```
+----+------+-----+----+--------+-----+
|id  |amount|fee  |exId|exAmount|exFee|
+----+------+-----+----+--------+-----+
|null|null  |null |1   |10.0    |5.0  |
|3   |90    |130.0|3   |90      |130.0|
|1   |10.00 |5.0  |1   |10.00   |5.0  |
+----+------+-----+----+--------+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I don't have my laptop handy but this looks like something that would work. thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939980/generic-join-between-two-dataframes-spark-scala