# generic join between two dataframes spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes i.e. left & right. I have working solution for my question. I need a way to make it generic. My question is at the end here.

## leftDF:

```
+------+---------+-------+-------+
|leftId|leftAltId|leftCur|leftAmt|
+------+---------+-------+-------+
|1     |100      |USD    |20     |
|2     |200      |INR    |100    |
|4     |500      |MXN    |100    |
+------+---------+-------+-------+
```

## rightDF:

```
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
|1      |300       |USD     |20      |
|3      |400       |MXN     |100     |
|4      |600       |MXN     |200     |
+-------+----------+--------+--------+
```

I want to perform a join between these two dataframes and I expect four dataframes as output

1. transactions that exists in leftDF & not in rightDF
2. transactions that exists in rightDF & not in leftDF
3. transactions that have alteast one of the ids common between two dataframes

   3.a Strict Match : same currency, amount between two dataframes. Example: transaction with id 1.

   3.b Relaxed Match : transactions that have same Id but different currency/amount combo. Example transaction with id 4.

Here's the desired output:

1. transactions that exists in leftDF & not in rightDF

   ```
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |leftId|leftAltId|leftCur|leftAmt|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |2     |200      |INR    |100    |null   |null      |null    |null    |
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   ```
2. transactions that exists in rightDF & not in leftDF

   ```
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |leftId|leftAtId|leftCur|leftAmt|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |null  |null     |null   |null   |3      |400       |MXN     |100     |
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   ```
3. transactions that have alteast one of the ids common between two dataframes

   ```
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |leftId|leftAltId|leftCur|leftAmt|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |1     |100      |USD    |20     |1      |300       |USD     |20      |
   |4     |500      |MXN    |100    |4      |600       |MXN     |200     |
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   ```

   3.a Strict Match : same currency, amount between two dataframes. Example: transaction with id 1.

   ```
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+        
   |leftId|leftAltId|leftCur|leftAmt|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |1     |100      |USD    |20     |1      |300       |USD     |20      |
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   ```

   3.b Relaxed Match : transactions that have same Id but different currency/amount combo. Example transaction with id 4.

   ```
    +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |leftId|leftAltId|leftCur|leftAmt|rightId|rightAltId|rightCur|rightAmt|
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   |4     |500      |MXN    |100    |4      |600       |MXN     |200     |
   +------+---------+-------+-------+-------+----------+--------+--------+
   ```

Here's the working code I have for it:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

val leftDF: DataFrame = Seq((1, 100, "USD", 20), (2, 200, "INR", 100), (4, 500, "MXN", 100)).toDF("leftId", "leftAltId", "leftCur", "leftAmt")
val rightDF: DataFrame = Seq((1, 300, "USD", 20), (3, 400, "MXN", 100), (4, 600, "MXN", 200)).toDF("rightId", "rightAltId", "rightCur", "rightAmt")

leftDF.show(false)
rightDF.show(false)
val idMatchQuery = leftDF("leftId") === rightDF("rightId") || leftDF("leftAltId") === rightDF("rightAltId")
val currencyMatchQuery = leftDF("leftCur") === rightDF("rightCur") && leftDF("leftAmt") === rightDF("rightAmt")
val leftOnlyQuery = (col("leftId").isNotNull && col("rightId").isNull) || (col("leftAltId").isNotNull && col("rightAltId").isNull)
val rightOnlyQuery = (col("rightId").isNotNull && col("leftId").isNull) || (col("rightAltId").isNotNull && col("leftAltId").isNull)
val matchQuery = (col("rightId").isNotNull && col("leftId").isNotNull) || (col("rightAltId").isNotNull && col("leftAltId").isNotNull)

val result = leftDF.join(rightDF, idMatchQuery, "fullouter")

val leftOnlyDF = result.filter(leftOnlyQuery)
val rightOnlyDF = result.filter(rightOnlyQuery)

val matchDF = result.filter(matchQuery)
val strictMatchDF = matchDF.filter(currencyMatchQuery.equalTo(true))
val relaxedMatchDF = matchDF.filter(currencyMatchQuery.equalTo(false))

leftOnlyDF.show(false)
rightOnlyDF.show(false)
matchDF.show(false)
strictMatchDF.show(false)
relaxedMatchDF.show(false)
```

## What I'm looking for:

I want to be able to take the column names to join on, as a list and make the code generic.

for e.g.

```
    val relaxedJoinList = Array(("leftId", "rightId"), ("leftAltId", "rightAltId"))
    val strictJoinList = Array(("leftCur", "rightCur"), ("leftAmt", "rightAmt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> > I want to be able to take the column names to join on, as a list and make the code generic.

This is not a perfect suggestion but would definitely help you get generalized. The suggestion is to go with `foldLeft`

```
val relaxedJoinList = Array(("leftId", "rightId"), ("leftAltId", "rightAltId"))
val rHead = relaxedJoinList.head

val strictJoinList = Array(("leftCur", "rightCur"), ("leftAmt", "rightAmt"))
val sHead = strictJoinList.head

val idMatchQuery = relaxedJoinList.tail.foldLeft(leftDF(rHead._1) === rightDF(rHead._2)){(x, y) => x || leftDF(y._1) === rightDF(y._2)}
val currencyMatchQuery = strictJoinList.tail.foldLeft(leftDF(sHead._1) === rightDF(sHead._2)){(x, y) => x && leftDF(y._1) === rightDF(y._2)}
val leftOnlyQuery = relaxedJoinList.tail.foldLeft(col(rHead._1).isNotNull && col(rHead._2).isNull){(x, y) => x || col(y._1).isNotNull && col(y._2).isNull}
val rightOnlyQuery = relaxedJoinList.tail.foldLeft(col(rHead._1).isNull && col(rHead._2).isNotNull){(x, y) => x || col(y._1).isNull && col(y._2).isNotNull}
val matchQuery = relaxedJoinList.tail.foldLeft(col(rHead._1).isNotNull && col(rHead._2).isNotNull){(x, y) => x || col(y._1).isNotNull && col(y._2).isNotNull}
```

The rest of the code is as yours

I hope the answer is helpful